# Hide second line on a multi-line mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been tasked with creating a drop down that has the style of[image]

The code for this is

```
<mat-select >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of source"
                style="min-height: 48px; line-height: normal; height: auto; padding: 10px 20px;" [value]="type.value">
        <div class="u-textSize14">{{type.displayName}}</div>
        <div class="u-textSize12">{{type.hint}}</div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When I select an option, the selected item appears as

"Standard UrlDomainName.com", is there any way I could hide the second line / hint when an item is selected and make it only appear when the mat select is open

Comment: You want to hide hint only on hover?

Comment: @Anjs when the item is selected, it concatinates the displayname and hint, i only want the display name to appear when an item is selected.

Comment: @CeriWestcott Did you solve the problem? I need a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize your selected option, use [`<mat-select-trigger>`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label) within the `<mat-select>`:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="foo">
    <mat-select-trigger>{{foo.value ? foo.value[0] : ''}}</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.val">{{item.label}} - {{item.desc}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```